# flex preloader not working with # in the url (deep linking)

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flash, swfaddress

I can't get flash preloaders to work when there is a a ***#*** in the url of my page (even without any deep linking libraries or logic).  I am using flex 3.3.  Flash plugins 9 and 10, all browsers.

There is this bug regarding ***#*** in the url preventing preloaders from working:
http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-14162

However, somehow, someone, somewhere has ways around this.  Here are somewhat working examples *(remember to clear your cache to ensure you see the preloader awesomeness)*:

- http://www.adobecards.com/index.html#wtf
- http://www.escriba.es/base_en.html#wtf
- http://www.sonypictures.com/movies/onceuponatimeinmexico/site/mexico.html#wtf
- http://instinct.ru/flash.html#wtf
- http://www.alternativedesign.tv/plant5.html#wtf

However, these do not work (no preloader at all or momentarily stuck on 100%):

- http://www.flashmagazine.com/articlefiles/preloader_finished.html#wtf
- http://www.mariaclaudiacortes.com/colors/Colors.html#wtf
- http://whoswestudios.com/flashsite.html#wtf
- http://www.iotashan.com/examples/NotSoCustomPreloader/index.html#wtf

So, what is going on here?  I suspect the flex framework.

Anyone know where to look in the flex code?  Or is this bug deeper than anyone but adobe can fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things going on here.

(1) Looks like the quickest pre-loader from my #wtf examples is from Adobe.  They load a very small container.swf, which then loads their 3mb main swf (amongst other biggies).

(2) Some of the others "preloaders" aren't really preloaders.  Their opening animations play when the whole thing is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem you are having is that you have your assets loading into the same frame as your preloader assets and code.  Flash doesn't display a frame until it has been loaded to its entirety, cause your preloader not to be seen during load, and then covered up by the new asset after.

As a flex developer you do not have a timeline, so this is why it is important to use a small "container" as you call it or as loader movie.  This movie is to have a tiny foot print so that it is available asap.  Upon completion of load, the container can then call the main movie into itself, tracking the incoming data with the ProgressEvent.

It is hard to know exactly what the issue is from what you have said, but this is a common problem.  Fonts, and any other embedded items either need to be embedded on frame 2 or laterm which I believe you can only do with the flash IDE, or you require the extra loader swf, lightweight and quick to load!

I have successfully deeplinked the following with preloaders
http://www.madagascargame.com
http://www.kungfupandagame.com